# Twisted ssh - session execCommand implementation

Tags: phpseclib, twisted.conch

Good day. I apologize for asking for obvious things because I'm writing in PHP and I know Python at the level "I started learning this yesterday". I've already spent a few days on this - but to no avail.
I downloaded twisted example of the SSH server for version 20.3 from here https://docs.twistedmatrix.com/en/twisted-20.3.0/conch/examples/. Line 162 has an execCommand method that I need to implement to make it work. Then I noticed a comment in this method "We don't support command execution sessions". Therefore, the question: Is this comment apply only to the example, or twisted library entirely. Ie, is it possible to implement this method to make the example server will work as I need?

More information. I don't think that this info is required to answer my questions above.
Why do I need it? I'm trying to compile an environment for writing functional (!) tests (there would be no such problems with the unit tests, I guess). Our API uses the SSH client (phpseclib / SSH2) by 30%+ of endpoints. Whatever I do, I had only 3 options of the results depending on how did I implement this method: (result: success, response: "" - empty; result: success, response: "1"; result: failed, response: "`Unable to fulfill channel request at… SSH2.php:3853`"). Those were for an SSH2 Client. If the error occurs (3rd case), the server shows logs in the terminal:

```
[SSHServerTransport, 0,127.0.0.1] Got remote error, code 11 reason: ""
[SSHServerTransport, 0,127.0.0.1] connection lost
```

Comment: What'd be more helpful is the phpseclib code that you're using to get the `Unable to fulfill channel request at… SSH2.php:3853` error. It'd also be good to have the SSH logs. You can get them by doing `define('NET_SSH2_LOGGING', 2)` at the top and `echo $ssh->getLog()` after you encounter that error.

Comment: It's also not clear what version of phpseclib you're using. You say `Unable to fulfill channel request at… SSH2.php:3853`. Cool. Line 3853 doesn't have an error like that in 3.0.8 (https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/blob/3.0.8/phpseclib/Net/SSH2.php#L3853), 2.0.31 (https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/blob/2.0.31/phpseclib/Net/SSH2.php#L3853) or 1.0.19 (https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/blob/1.0.19/phpseclib/Net/SSH2.php#L3853)...

Comment: Anyway, looking at sshsimpleserver.py it looks like a lot of the methods in it are just stubs that are intended to be filled in by the end user. Their `openShell` method uses a made up "Echo Protocol" that "_Just echo the received data and and if Ctrl+C is received, close the session_". So if you wanted to test that "Echo Protocol" out with phpseclib you'd do `$ssh->write("hello, world!\n");` and it should echo that back out to you. If you want TwistedSSH to do anything more useful than that then you'd need to implement that functionality in yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I just found this works:

```
def execCommand(self, protocol, cmd):
    protocol.write('Some text to return')
    protocol.session.conn.sendEOF(protocol.session)
```

If I don't send EOF the client throws a timeout error.